# Show some news in model popup when user login to Salesforce

Tags: notification, popup-window, push-notification

I want to show a popup when user logs into the Salesforce org. It is similar to the popups which Salesforce shows on login for maintenance notice.

Is there any feature in Salesforce, which allows us to show such popup (for org level news/updates) when user login to the system?

We can embed a page/component in the home page layout and show the popup. But, it will not work for news/updates as I want to show this popup only a few times in a month.

Let us know, if there is any feature/product of Salesforce can be used for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Login Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_create.htm).